# ActionBar is null after migration to Gradle

Tags: android, gradle, android-actionbar, adt

This is a really weird error as far as I can understand.
I just migrated a project from ADT to Gradle. And the same exact code is now crashing on startup. 
It seems the problem is that the ActionBar that previously was perfectly valid now is null.

The code is within a class that `extends Activity` and is called from within `onCreate`

```
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    if (actionBar==null) Log.d(TAG,"AB null.");
```

Not sure what more code to post, since I'm really puzzeled why this worked just 30 minutes ago and not at all now.
The project is not using any support package, and only targets 4.0 and later.

Comment: You are using a theme that does not have an action bar, presumably. What theme is this activity using?

Comment: @CommonsWare I'm using android:theme="@style/AppTheme" in my manifest. Not changing it in any activity.

Comment: Then please post the definition of `AppTheme`. For example, are you inheriting from `Theme.AppCompat`?

Comment: @CommonsWare This is quite simple `<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light"></style>`

Comment: Well, now, that's strange. If you comment out the code trying to use `ActionBar` and run the app, are you seeing an action bar?

Comment: @CommonsWare Nope. The app runs but without any `ActionBar` or home button. It is just a very narrow line with only the apps name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Theme.Light` does not have an action bar. That is the old Android 1.x/2.x theme, with the old title bar (thin grey strip with the app's name).

`Theme.Holo.Light`, and a `targetSdkVersion` of 11+, will give you an action bar.

Comment: Spot on! I can't really tell why this did work with ADT but changing it to Holo.Light fixed the problem while running Gradle.